# How to read PivotTable with Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table

I need read a Pivot Table from a sheet. This is the [file](http://www.anp.gov.br/?dw=8485) and the sheet is *Plan 01*.

This is the Pivot Table:

[image: Pivot Table]

How read this in Java?

Comment: What do you want to read? The full pivot table? A particular pivot result?

Comment: The last row (with bold caracteres) of a particular pivor result, like 'ÓLEO COMBUSTÍVEL (m3)'.